Docker with zookeeper kafka and kafka ui
I'm getting this error on zookeeper
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,990] ERROR cnxn.saslServer is null: cnxn object did not initialize its saslServer properly. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
2024-09-06 12:46:08 [2024-09-06 15:46:08,383] WARN Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x100005f45720000, likely client has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:49 [2024-09-06 15:46:49,536] INFO Expiring session 0x100005f45720000, timeout of 40000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)

I'm getting this error on kafka
NFO SASL config status: Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:05 [2024-09-06 15:46:05,744] WARN Session 0x0 for server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:05 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2024-09-06 12:46:05     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
2024-09-06 12:46:05     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
2024-09-06 12:46:05     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
2024-09-06 12:46:05     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:344)
2024-09-06 12:46:05     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1289)
2024-09-06 12:46:06 [2024-09-06 15:46:06,848] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
2024-09-06 12:46:06 [2024-09-06 15:46:06,848] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:06 [2024-09-06 15:46:06,848] INFO SASL config status: Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:06 [2024-09-06 15:46:06,849] WARN Session 0x0 for server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:06 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2024-09-06 12:46:06     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
2024-09-06 12:46:06     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
2024-09-06 12:46:06     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
2024-09-06 12:46:06     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:344)
2024-09-06 12:46:06     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1289)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,957] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,957] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,957] INFO SASL config status: Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,957] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.18.0.3:51600, server: zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,987] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181, session id = 0x100005f45720000, negotiated timeout = 40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,991] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client'. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.
2024-09-06 12:46:07     at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.createSaslToken(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:310)
2024-09-06 12:46:07     at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.respondToServer(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:270)
2024-09-06 12:46:07     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:936)
2024-09-06 12:46:07     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:98)
2024-09-06 12:46:07     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
2024-09-06 12:46:07     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1289)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,991] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x100005f45720000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2024-09-06 12:46:07 [2024-09-06 15:46:07,991] ERROR Error occurred while connecting to Zookeeper server[zookeeper:2181]. Authentication failed.  (io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus)
2024-09-06 12:46:08 Using log4j config /etc/kafka/log4j.properties


Follow my code:
docker-compose.yml

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.4
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true'
      ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: "true"
      JVMFLAGS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/zookeeper_jaas.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./zookeeper_jaas.conf:/etc/zookeeper/zookeeper_jaas.conf
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"  # SASL/PLAIN port
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SET_ACL: true
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT, SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_server_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:9093
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='admin' password='admin-secret';"


kafka_server_jaas.conf

KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
   user_user="user-secret";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="kafka"
   password="kafka-secret";
};
Server {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   user_kafka="kafka-secret";
};

zookeeper_jaas.conf

Server {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   user_kafka="kafka-secret";
};

I need assistance with configuring a Docker image using docker-compose where I'm implementing SASL authentication. Specifically, I'm encountering issues during the setup process. The problem seems to be related to integrating SASL authentication correctly with the Docker containers. Can someone guide me through the steps to resolve this issue or provide insight into common pitfalls when using SASL authentication in a Docker environment?

KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS should list kafka:9093 not localhost. Also Kafka doesn't need Zookeeper anymore. Are you sure you need it?
